# Boolean not working not sure why

Tags: modifiers

I can't figure this out. My geometry is about as simple as it gets, a solidified cube with some extrusions to make a building. I have no doubles, my normals are all facing outward, I have no nonmanifold geometry. I placed the boolean modifier on a cube to have it cut through the building but it still isn't working, any help would be appreciated. Below is my file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ni3dds2R7q9e4eNVVJBpxgr0tjf7Rck8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The geometry of "Destructor Rrrr Cube" object is not cube, the bounds box is just displayed. Select `Textured` in the `Display As` pull down menu instead of `Bounds`.

[image]